# How to get the specific data format from different domain using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

What kind of data format is this and how can i parse it using jQuery?

```
s:7:"resdata";a:8:{s:8:"greeting";s:7:"abc9999";s:4:"svID";s:6:"Serwer";s:7:"version";s:3:"2.1";s:4:"lang";s:2:"pl";s:6:"svDate";s:19:"2010-08-31T12:53:51";s:6:"access";s:3:"all";s:10:"connection";s:2:"OK";s:10:"ip:connect";s:13:"11.111.11.111";}
```

Comment: Does the server provide you with a mime-type indicating the format of the data? Looks like JSON but doesn't hurt to check

Comment: @James Goodwin Console gives me: "Resource interpreted as Other but transferred with MIME type undefined."

Comment: @easyrider, did you manage to resolve this question?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [JSON](http://www.json.org/). Check out jQuery's [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) and [parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) api.

Comment: there are syntax errors when I interpret it as Json - I've already tried getJson on this

Comment: It looks like JSON but it may be malformed.....  It's my best guess.  Since you are getting it from elsewhere do you have a way of finding out from the source what it is?

Comment: Looks like JSON to me too. If you have php to hand, try running it through json_decode()? That would at least let you know if we've identified it correctly :)